# How to store a struct that uses monomorphization (static dispatch) into a field of another struct?

Tags: rust

In the code below you can see my attempt at storing the struct in question in another struct.

```
trait example_trait_object {}

struct example_struct<T: example_trait_object> {
    a: T,
}

struct this_will_hold_example_struct {
    a: example_struct,
}
```

But if i try to compile this, I'll receive an error.

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
```

I don't want to hardcode the generic type, is there any way around this problem?

P.S. I only wish to use dynamic dispatch when there's really no other way around this problem.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed Yes, it did. Thank you very much!